# Can i view Cloudant Local Documents via browser UI

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm using IBM Cloudant, with some config data stored in `local documents`.

I can access these via the REST API, but is it possible to view them from the Browser GUI interface that IBM provides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local documents are invisible from the UI and are only accessible via the API if you know the document key. For example, if you created this document:

```
{"_id":"_local/bob",
  "name":"Bob",
  "surname":"TheBuilder"}
```

... you can really only retrieve it by doing:

```
https://<service_url>/<dbname>/_local/bob
```

**OR**
you can see it in the UI by modifying the dashboard url like this:

```
https://<service_url>/dashboard.html#database/<dbname>/_local/bob
```

Using local documents is quite a niche use case. They are used by the Cloudant replicator to store state that doesn't need to be replicated.

When using PouchDB it can be useful to use local documents in an in-browser PouchDB database to store local state/config that you don't want replicated to the Cloud.