# Editing a `local document` in CouchDb using fauxton

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0, fauxton

Am I right in thinking that it is not possible to edit/view a `local document` in a CouchDb database using Fauxton?

I can't see how to do it from the UI, and Googling returns no references to being able to do it.

Local documents aren't a major part of CouchDb, but this omission does seem an oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71619346/can-i-view-cloudant-local-documents-via-browser-ui) still applies because the Cloudant dashboard is basically the same as the Fauxton one, with a few additions.

However, I have made a slight edit to that answer because you **can** access these local documents in the UI by modifying the dashboard URL with the document ID.

It is not pretty, but it works!

Comment: Thanks for that Daniel

Note: it appears the `_local/settings` trick works on Cloudant but not CouchDb.
 
For `CouchDb` I get a `does not exist` warning: https://i.gyazo.com/167b3a07710149569683747de44238aa.mp4

Comment: FWIW, see this https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/pull/1000